# Norm of projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-matrices, projection-matrices, matrix-norms

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n \times m$ matrix.  Here the $a_{ij}$ are  independent identically distributed random variables. The covariance matrix $M=\frac 1n AA^T$. It is known that the maximum eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix is bounded by its largest diagonal element. Thus, the Euclidean norm
$$
\|M\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Mx,x\rangle \geq \sup_i M_{ii}.
$$

How can I get a similar bound if matrix the $M=PX$, where $X$ is some random vector in $\mathbb R^n$ and $P$ is an orthogonal projection in $\mathbb R^n$?

(Also, if I am right, there can be a few possibilities for the orthogonal projection, i.e. when it is orthogonal to the vector $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ and when it is orthogonal to the vector $(1,1,0,0,\ldots)$. What is the difference?)

Comment: On a point of terminology, if $\ A\ $ is a matrix with random variables as entries, its covariance  matrix, as I understand that term to be normally use, would not be the $\ n\times n\ $ matrix $\ M\ $, which has $\ i,j\ $ entry $\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{jk}\ $, in general a *random variable*, but the $\ n^2\times n^2\ $ matrix  whose $\ ij, kl\ $ entry is the *constant* $\ \mathbb{E}\left(a_{ij}a_{kl}-\mathbb{E}\left(a_{ij}\right)\mathbb{E}\left(a_{kl}\right)\right)\ $.